# Can I run Asp.Net Cassini Web Server in 32 bit mode?

Tags: asp.net, x86, webserver, cassini

I have a project that depends on the SigPlusNet 32 bit dll that I cannot upgrade. It has been suggested to me that it would work if I got IIS running in 32 bit mode but I have been running the Visual Studio Cassini webserver and cannot install IIS at this time.

I just need to run on my machine so that I can fix a few bugs. Can I run cassini in 32 bit mode?

Answer (score 1):

I was under the impression that [Cassini was 32bit](http://www.controlsystemworks.com/articles/UsingCassiniWebServer.html).

Have you tried using [IIS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038) ?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to enable it at the moment

Comment: And you are also completely correct that cassini does seem to be 32 bit. Well darn...

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - First, install VS SP1, that will have an option to enable IIS Express if it's installed.  Second, Install IIS Express via the download on the webpage. http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=IISExpress